# Linux From Scratch/LFS 11.0 Systemd kernel boots to black screen

Tags: linux, grub2, lfs

I have a new build of LFS 11.0-systemd on a bare metal Thinkpad X250. Everything is compiled and setup with Fedora 36 as the host system. I'm using BIOS boot mode.

The system boots to GRUB, but when I select the LFS kernel, I get a brief flash of kernel messages before a blank screen that stays forever. The system does seem to boot on some level - I can see all the messages in the journal in the chroot, although I don't see anything that tells me why the screen is blank. For what it's worth, the LFS GRUB boots Fedora 36 just fine.

Some possibly interesting info from the journal:

```
May 21 01:14:45 EDITME systemd[1]: First Boot Complete was skipped because of a failed condition check (ConditionFirstBoot=yes).
May 21 01:14:45 EDITME systemd[1]: Commit a transient machine-id on disk was skipped because of a failed condition check (ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/etc/machine-id).
May 21 01:14:45 EDITME systemd[1]: Startup finished in 2.500s (kernel) + 1.785s (userspace) = 4.285s.
```

For reference:

LFS /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sda3     /            ext4    defaults            1     1
/dev/sda7     /boot        ext4    defaults             0     0
/dev/sda6     swap         swap     pri=1               0     0
```

LFS lsblk from chroot

```
    NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
|-sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part   #BIOS boot 
|-sda2   8:2    0    50G  0 part   #Fedora root
|-sda3   8:3    0    20G  0 part / #LFS root
|-sda4   8:4    0    10G  0 part   #LFS /home
|-sda5   8:5    0    10G  0 part   #LFS /opt
|-sda6   8:6    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
`-sda7   8:7    0   512M  0 part /boot #LFS /boot
zram0  252:0    0   7.5G  0 disk [SWAP]
```

LFS grub.cfg

```
# Begin /boot/grub/grub.cfg
set default=0
set timeout=5

insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,7)

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux 5.17.7-lfs-r11.1-119-systemd" {
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.17.7-lfs-r11.1-119-systemd root=/dev/sda3 ro
}

menuentry "Fedora 36 Workstation" {
        linux (hd0,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz-5.17.6-300.fc36.x86_64 root=/dev/sda2 ro
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be going awry would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you're not alone. This thing happened to me also. I thought I compiled the wrong graphics modules and recompiled the kernel with what I thought was the right graphics drivers for my computer. This fixed nothing, So, I recompiled the kernel again with my ubuntu's default kernel configuration and this fixed the issue to some extent as I saw a bit more verbose messages before the kernel panicked! I have no idea on whats wrong with the newly built system, but I am still working on a fix.

EDIT: Add 'nomodeset' after linux /boot/vmlinuz-xx-xx-xx-systemd root=/dev/sdXY in grub.cfg
Add it so it looks like this:

```
menuentry "Linux From Scratch" {   
       linux /boot/vmlinux-xx-xx-xx-systemd root=/dev/sdXY ro       nomodeset
}
```

I believe that this problem is caused due to lack of appropiate graphics modules in the kernel.